# Passing Rundeck options to Ansible as tags list

Tags: automation, ansible, rundeck

I have an Ansible playbook which has multiple tasks,each tagged differently and i'm trying to start it using Rundeck's (Ansible Playbook Workflow Node Step) with rundeck option for selecting multiple values which i want to pass as "Extra Ansible arguments" essentially i want to be able to chose what task in the playbook to be ran.But i'm getting some really weird problems.
This is the output i get when running the rundeck job:

```
procArgs: [ansible-playbook, all.yml -l, 10.100.5.103, -vvv, --private-key=/key/location/id_rsa, --user=slave, --become-method=sudo, --tags=libs,master]
```

And the job finishes successfully in seconds without actually doing anything

```
PLAYNOOK: all.yml ******************************
1 plays in all.yml

PLAY [test]**************************************
Meta: ran handlers
Meta: ran handlers
Meta: ran handlers

PLAY RECAP **************************************
```

When i execute the command that i essentially get from the output from the terminal everything runs as it should:

```
ansible-playbook all.yml -l 10.100.5.103 -vvv --private-key=/key/location/id_rsa --user=slave --become-method=sudo --tags=libs,master
```

I couldn't find any recent information about using multiple select option as tags and im just confused from this weird behavior(I tried with just 1 tag and it still doesn't work).
This is my rundeck job definition:

```
Steps:  

Ansible Playbook Workflow Node Step. Runs an Ansible Playbook
Ansible base directory path: /etc/ansible Playbook: all.yml Extra Variables:

Extra Ansible arguments: --tags=${option.modules} SSH Authentication: privateKey SSH Key Storage Path: keys/ssh/vmkey

If a step fails: Stop at the failed step.
Strategy:
Node First Execute all steps on a node before proceeding to the nextnode.
Verbose Logging:    Enabled
Nodes:  Include nodes matching: name: 10.100.5.103
Execute on up to 1 Node at a time.
If a node fails: Fail the step without running on any remaining nodes.
Sort nodes by name in ascending order.
```

This is all hapening on 2 ubuntu VM's for Ansible version 2.7.1,Rundeck 3.0.8

Any help is valuable,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not deeply familiar with Rundeck so not speaking from direct experience or able to test, but those ','s look a bit odd in:

```
procArgs: [ansible-playbook, all.yml -l, 10.100.5.103, -vvv, --private-key=/key/location/id_rsa, --user=slave, --become-method=sudo, --tags=libs,master]
```

- should there be a comma after `all.yml`?
- should the string in `--tags=libs,master` be quoted because it contains a literal comma?

Comment: Yes there is a comma after "all.yml" i just missed it when coping it. I tried adding quotes around the values, i even tried hard coding them in and it still does the same